# Pyspark DD-MMM-YYYY (string format) to timestamp

Tags: string, datetime, pyspark

Hello I am new to the Pyspark, I have a string Variable that contain date DD-MMM-YYYY format and i want to convert that into a time stamp ?

24-MAY-2019 - String format to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`to_timestamp(preferred) (or) from_unixtime and unix_timestamp`** functions:

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df.selectExpr("to_timestamp(dt,'dd-MMM-yyyy') as tt").show()
+-------------------+
|                 tt|
+-------------------+
|2019-05-24 00:00:00|
+-------------------+

df1.withColumn("ts",to_timestamp(col("dt"),'dd-MMM-yyyy')).show()
+-----------+-------------------+
|         dt|                 ts|
+-----------+-------------------+
|24-MAY-2019|2019-05-24 00:00:00|
+-----------+-------------------+

#using from_unixtime and unix_timestamp
df1.withColumn("ts",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("dt"),'dd-MMM-yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS').cast("timestamp")).show(10,False)
+-----------+-----------------------+
|dt         |ts                     |
+-----------+-----------------------+
|24-MAY-2019|2019-05-24 00:00:00.000|
+-----------+-----------------------+

#using unix_timestamp and casting to timestamp
df1.withColumn("ts",unix_timestamp(col("dt"),'dd-MMM-yyyy').cast("timestamp")).show()
#+-----------+-------------------+
#|         dt|                 ts|
#+-----------+-------------------+
#|24-MAY-2019|2019-05-24 00:00:00|
#+-----------+-------------------+
```